# How to get random youtube videos with a specific number of views?

Tags: video, youtube, statistics, youtube-api

Using the following code, I managed to display random videos from youtube on my website. I was just wondering if it was possible now to select only videos with a specific number of views?

*For example purposes, let's say they need to have more than 100 views.*

I guess I need to use the Youtube API with *statistics* and *ViewCount*, but I didn't manage to find a way yet. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for( var i=0; i < 4; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    var link='<iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=' + text + '&orderby=reversedPosition&autoplay=0&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>' ;
    document.write(link);
    </script>
```

Comment: the link you have added is broken !!! any why why asking question you should add script/code  with your question for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have added the code accordingly.

Comment: It's possible but clunky, since afaik there isn't a way to search by viewCount. You could use the API to grab a random set of videos and compare each video's viewCount with your threshold.